# Hide empty categories from get_categories

Tags: php, categories, query, archives

I'm trying to hide the empty categories (with no posts associated) from a list in an archive page. 
I'm using `hide_empty` as suggested on Wordpress codex but it's not working, the code outputs all categories:

```
<ul class="filter-menu">
  <?php $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    foreach(get_categories('parent=0&hide_empty=1') as $category) {
      echo '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'. $category->slug.'" >' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how could I modify the code to make it work?

Comment: Are you *sure* categories you think are empty are _indeed_ empty? Go to Posts > Categories in the admin and check that the post count column is `0` for those in question.

Answer (score -3):

Try this hide_empty=1 it should be hide_empty=0

Comment: Please explain why this would help

Comment: no, there should be 1, OP does it correctly. Just something other problem.